# Number of possible IOIO pulse inputs

Tags: digital-logic, android, input, pulse

Looking at this page it mentions that double precision digital pulse input (32-bit timer) can be divided into 2 single precision 16-bit timers.

https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/Pulse-Input

It says there are 3 single and 3 double modules.

Does this mean that 9 pins can be used for single precision pulse input? (3 single + 3*2)?

Is this correct?

Comment: Much obviously necessary context is clearly missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PIC24FJ256GB206 microcontroller used on the IOIO board does have 9 Input Capture modules, and the input pins for these modules are remappable using PPS, so unless there's some external limitation imposed by the way the board is constructed you should be able to use all 9 as 16-bit (single precision) inputs.